# What does "Attribution" mean exactly when using downloaded fonts?

Tags: fonts, typography, copyright

The fonts that are free for commercial use are sometimes under Creative Commons licenses, such as [CC BY-ND 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/3.0/), which require you to give attribution to the creator. Does this mean you have to attribute whenever you use the font in some text in a project, or is it only when you redistribute the font?

I mean, not many projects leave room for crediting a font, right?

Comment: It's best to ask the author. While I love the idea of CC, I usually avoid them due to the fact that the conditions are rarely explicit and always hard to decipher.

Answer (score 2):

Some of your question is better directed to a legal professional as all license/legal questions require legal opinions (and thus they are not a good question for the Graphic Design StackExchange).

The most practical means of meeting the CC-Attribution-No Derivatives requirements is to provide a noticeable area in your work that attributes the creator of the resource used and links back to that resource's web site (or the creator's website). This attribution should be provided for every project that uses this resource. The no-derivative portion of the license would actually require a legal professional to decide if that means that any work created with the resource then becomes a derivative work and thus can't be re-distributed or whether that portion just applies to the original resource. Or a written note from the creator explaining what they meant by choosing this license.

I am not a lawyer and I'm **definitely not your lawyer**, so if you have further questions about what is allowed or not allowed with this license, please consult a legal professional.

Comment: I couldn't put it any better than this. You'll need to find a space to put the attribution, or get a font that you pay for and therefore don't have to attribute.